# Null runtime exception when using IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: powershell

I am trying to init a config object with string value or file content value (if string variable is null or empty).

```
$ConfigObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Name"        = $env:OOO_NAME
        "Content"=
        if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:NOTE) -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:PUBLISH_FILEPATH))
        {
             Write-Host "Check input"
             exit 1
        }
        elseif(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:PUBLISH_NOTE))
        {
             $env:PUBLISH_NOTE ############# **it throws exception here.**
        }
        else
        {
             Get-Content ($env:PUBLISH_FILEPATH)
        }
}
```

**It works fine when this script execute by itself, but it yells RuntimeException after executing several PowerShell scripts.** The following is exception info:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ $env:PUBLISH_NOTE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

It really doesn't make any sense to me, since I use **$env:{environment variable name}** to access system environment variables and why doesn't it yell at earier lines such as

```
elseif(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:PUBLISH_NOTE))
```

Please kindly explain what's the root case of this runtime exception.

Comment: Did you create these environment variables?  Because they don't exist by default.

Comment: Yes, I created them and it surely doesn't exist by default. Based on the script provided, if $env:PUBLISH_NOTE is null then it will not execute the value assignment, and it will not yell the exception.

Comment: Is this the full code? I cant recreate the issue. Running your logic works fine. If i simple run `$env:PUBLISH_NOTE` I get no exception and the variable does not exist on my system. It just returns nothing.

Comment: I would agree with @Nick. I don't think error is coming from this peace of code. Also, strange thing is with tilde signs under error. They usually have exact the same character count as the line above, which is not the case in your description. Can you run it in in ISE for example to see exactly in which line it is throwing the error? Or, add break point to check variables inside if block.

Comment: @Nick This script will not yell any run-time exception when it's running by itself. It throws the exception after many PS scripts executed and throw the exception from the provided code.

Comment: What kind of scripts? Do they run your scope or other users scope? Is there a pattern to the script that runs before the error?

Comment: @Seth some of them are windows bash scripts and some of them are PowerShell scripts.

Comment: @Igor You are right. I think I will try to add some break points and reproduce the exception. Thanks!!